# How to shift whole pandas dataframe to right in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When jupyter notebook/lab displays the dataframe it is always left-aligned. I want to shift the whole dataframe-structure position to some units to the right. What code do I have to add to get the required changes (i.e. to shift my dataframe position) ?

[image]

Comment: Every column is already right aligned though?

Comment: No, I want to shift the whole dataframe-structure to right direction

Comment: @slothfulwave612: I have updated the answer check it now. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just inspect the element. The element is `Out[]:` `output_subarea` .

Write your own css.

Try:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

CSS = """
.output_subarea {
  margin-left:100px;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

---

```
display(df)
```

[image]

**update:**

Do it in this way(in one cell define them):

```
display(HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS)))
display(df)
```

Comment: Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: Posted the screenshot (in the edit section of the question)

Comment: put `df = pd.DataFrame ..... to next cell. make one cell for html thing don't post the whole thing. That's why not working.

Comment: Hey, can you check out the edit section again it's still not working.

Comment: can you inspect the element and see what  is the div name in your case and also check the ipython version and jupyter version too. mine is ipython==7.7.0

Comment: I am using v7.19.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226102/discussion-between-pygirl-and-slothfulwave612).

Comment: You didn't check on localhost?. Are you checking only on colab? but it seems in colab there is an issue.

Comment: I have raised an issue: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1783